# Is a function passed as props in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and came across this React code:

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = { username: '' };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WelcomeMessage username={this.state.username} />
        <SettingsForm
          username={this.state.username}
          updateUsername={newUsername => {
            this.setState({ username: newUsername });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The question is what is this code about:

```
updateUsername={newUsername => {
            this.setState({ username: newUsername });
          }}
```

Is a function passed as props???

Comment: Yes, it is. It's very common in React.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, hey Robin, ok I understand when we use, say, updateUserName={this.update} but what happens in that code exactly I cannot get. Please can you kindly explain?:)

Comment: It's the same thing. The `this.update` that you're used to will be a reference to a function. This is just passing a function as a prop in a slightly different way - but the result, from the point of view of the child component, is the same.

Comment: The key difference to this.update is, that it will be generated on every render which may be to unnecessary rerenders if combined with withMemo/Pure components.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function is passed as props in the `Dashboard` component.

By passing:

```
updateUsername={newUsername => {
  this.setState({ username: newUsername });
}}
```

the child component can call `updateUsername(_myNewUserName_)` which will set the state in its parent component.

It may be beneficial to take a look at [event bubbling](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/event-bubbling/) to see this concept in action.

Hope this helps,